# 2D index-Array out of bounds

Tags: java

For the sake of testing if my logic works(I think It should but Its not) I am doing small operations in a paint method, I just didn't want to mess my main project up.

I have X and Y positions of Tiles on a board and want to just make sure I have the right X and Y so I made this method:

```
private void drawBoard(Graphics2D g2d) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/background.png"));
    g2d.drawImage(image,0,0, null,null);
    int col = 2;
    int rows = 6;
    int[][] RedArray =
        {{274, 399},
        {274, 440},
        {274, 480},
        {274, 520},
        {274, 560},
        {274, 600}};

    for(int i = 0; i < col; i++){
        for(int j = 0; i < rows; j++){
            g2d.drawRect(RedArray[rows][col], RedArray[rows][col], 25, 25);
        }
    }

}
```

this is supposed to get the x,y values from the RedArray and then paint them onto the board but I am getting an index out of bound error and I can't seem to kick it

Answer (score 2):

In your second for loop you have i < rows, needs to be j < rows like so:

```
for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
```

Also `RedArray[rows][col]` should be `RedArray[j][i]`

Comment: That isn't the actual problem. `RedArray[rows][col]` should be `RedArray[j][i]`

Comment: @PigeonMilk Stories, I understand your frustration but please use don't take the name Christ in vain here, thank you!

Comment: @cricket_007 you're right that is also an issue, answer should be combined with another.  I will edit mine.

Comment: @Cameron637 Don't go thinking this place has anything to do with religion. Cricket had no intention of insulting your God. He was just using English to protest frustration. There is no need to take offense when he was not giving you any. Your interpretation is at fault, not his English. :P

Comment: @blahfunk Christ isn't an English term, it's a name.  I was simply asking him not to use it around me, as a mother would ask someone not to use the f word around her child.  I'm not trying to restrict anyone's rights or push my beliefs on anyone else, just asking that my beliefs and those of any other Christian users be respected as well.

Comment: @Cameron637 Welcome to the Internet where free speech means grow some thick skin. BTW: Christ is a Title, not a Name. Jesus was his name.

Comment: @blahfunk Thanks, I know very well people will continue to trample on other's beliefs regardless of what they say, but it is my duty as a Christian to at least say something defending His name.  If they continue to use it regardless then so be it.  And you're right it is a title, but it's still referring to a person as a name would.  It is still not an term like any curse word.

Comment: @Cameron637 You are the EXACT reason why I left the church and ppl like you continue to assure me I made the right decision. If you honestly think what you are doing is helping anything in any way, you, sir, are the reason why this world has gone to hell. Bcz you think you and everyone else should bow down, submit, etc,  to what you believe is true, ignoring all others. Thanks for helping to re-enforce those beliefs!

Comment: @blahfunk this conversation has gone far enough it is not something that should be carried on in stackoverflow comments so I will leave my last remark here.  How do you not realize that you're the one doing the oppressing? As I said, I am not forcing my beliefs on anyone.  I asked politely and left it at that, if he continues to use it then so be it.  You are trying to forbid Christians from even asking politely that people don't disrespect their God.  I respect everyone's beliefs and would just as soon defend an atheist under attack for his beliefs.

Comment: He wasn't talking about your God. In his mind, when he said that, God, yours, his, or anyone elses, was no where on his mind. In effect you have said, "You may have meant 'abc' by your comment, but what I heard was 'xyz'. Even though 'xyz' makes no sense here as God has nothing to due with a loop, I am telling you that is what you said and you shouldn't do that." Do you see the level of crazy there? @Cameron637

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110573/discussion-between-cameron637-and-blahfunk).

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> RedArray[rows][col]
> ```

You want `i` and `j` here, not `rows` and `col`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this

```
private void drawBoard(Graphics2D g2d) throws IOException {
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/background.png"));
g2d.drawImage(image,0,0, null,null);
int col = 2;
int rows = 6;
int[][] RedArray =
    {{274, 399},
    {274, 440},
    {274, 480},
    {274, 520},
    {274, 560},
    {274, 600}};

for(int i = 0; i < col; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < rows; j++){
        g2d.drawRect(RedArray[j][i], RedArray[j][i], 25, 25); // not RedArray[rows][cols]
    }
}
```

}